Why is the racial health inequality so different in Arkansas particularly wrt Native Americans?
The Commonwealth Fund Scorecard on State Health System Performance rate many metrics for the health system across the US states.  One such metric is what rates of preventable death members of different ethnic groups experience across the different states.  The graph of this is below, and there are some common trends in the data.  Two such trends are the low and fairly stable rate in the Asian American and Native Hawaiian/Pacific Islander (AANHPI) community and the high rate in the Native American and Alaska Native (AIAN) community.  However in Arkansas only these rates are roughly reversed, with the Native American rate in line with the AANHPI rate in other states, and the AANHPI rate about 50% higher than any other state.
Is there a reason for this appreantly quite stark difference?

